# Regular Expression not evaluating as expected

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

I am attempting to evaluate the below code but it isn't returning what is expected.
Testing with the string "CityName!!!" returns true instead of false.  My expression should only allow a string that is letters and spaces, any length, starting with a letter.

```
protected bool isValidCityName(string cityName)
    {
        Regex cityMatch = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+");

        return cityMatch.IsMatch(cityName);
    }
```

Thank You

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern just checks that the string *begins* with that pattern. You need to include an end anchor (`$`) to ensure there are no trailing characters after the match:

```
Regex cityMatch = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$");
```

Also, you may want to consider using the `IgnoreCase` option:

```
Regex cityMatch = new Regex(@"^[a-z][a-z\s]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

And use [Unicode categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories), if you need your application to support other languages / locales (e.g. Québec):

```
Regex cityMatch = new Regex(@"^\p{L}[\p{L}\s]+$");
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  I knew about most characters, but never had to worry about the anchor before.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `$` to the end:

```
Regex cityMatch = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$");
```

[Example](http://www.rubular.com/r/zXVu1KoMoh)

Right now, your expression only requires the string to *start with* those characters.  The `^` denotes the beginning of the string, the `+` means *one or more of*.  The `$` means *end of the string*.

This is the same with pretty much any regular expression parser.